# Get aiohttp results as string

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to get data from a website using async in python. As an example I used this code (under A Better Coroutine Example): https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/26/python-3-an-intro-to-asyncio/

Now this works fine, but it writes the binary chunks to a file and I don't want it in a file. I want the resulting data directly. But I currently have a list of coroutine objects which I can not get the data out of.

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout

async def fetch(session, url):
    with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()


async def main(loop, urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        tasks = [fetch(session, url) for url in urls]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return tasks

# time normal way of retrieval
if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = [a list of urls..]

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    details_async = loop.run_until_complete(main(loop, urls))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in `return tasks` at the end of `main()`, which is not present in the original article. Instead of returning the coroutine objects (which are not useful once passed to `asyncio.gather`), you should be returning the tuple returned by `asyncio.gather`, which contains the results of running the coroutines in correct order. For example:

```
async def main(loop, urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        tasks = [fetch(session, url) for url in urls]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return results
```

Now `loop.run_until_complete(main(loop, urls))` will return a tuple of texts in the same order as the URLs.

Comment: i did the exact same code still get [None, None, None, None, None]

Comment: @AkashRanjan Did you actually return the data from `fetch`?

Comment: yes, also added print , which shows proper data being returned, but somehow not reflecting in the return output nor in the print next to await gather line

Comment: @AkashRanjan You should probably ask a separate question and show the code you're running (preferably with a minimal example that still reproduces the issue).