# Python - looping through variable for multiple get requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape ticket availability across multiple event dates.

Each event date has its own eventID, so for the 23 possible dates the eventids are 1001-1023

I have started to do this manually, and the below gives me all the seats availability for a given date, but repeating this 22 times cannot be the most efficient way.

```
import requests
import json 

f = open('tickets.txt','a')

r = requests.get('https://www.website.com/events/1000/tickets/seatmap?sectionid=3')
d = json.loads(r.text)
zones = d['zones']
for key, value in zones.iteritems() :
    print >>f, (key, value)
```

I want to loop through the eventIDs and print all availability across all dates at once. However im having trouble building up the request/URL. So far I've created:

```
eventIDs =  range(1001, 1023)
baseurl = "https://www.website.com/events/"
sectionId = "/tickets/seatmap?sectionId=3"
```

UPDATE: I think i've got there, this that i think works...

```
for i in eventIDs:
    url=baseurl+str(i)+sectionId
    r = requests.get(url) 
    d = json.loads(r.text)
    print >>f, (d)
```

Is this the best way to do this? Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Pool.map function from multiprocessing module to query URLs in parallel. I think you are doing fine in general.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider making your rest calls *async*. If you want to stick with `requests`-ish style, you can use [`grequests`](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests):

```
# Python3
import grequests

event_ids =  range(1001, 1023)
base_url = "https://www.website.com/events/"
section_id = "/tickets/seatmap?sectionId=3"
# Create an array of urls
urls = [base_url + str(i) + section_id for i in event_ids ]
# Preapare requests
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
# Send them
results = grequests.map(rs)
```

Or you can make use of `asyncio` with [`aiohttp`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). If you're interested in it and want to check how it looks like, you can visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53336675/4636715)